# a cleaner way of representing double quote?

Tags: c#

really simple question... just want to represent double quote " without needing to do "" or \"

cases that I'm aware of:

```
var s=@"123 "" 456 """;

var s="123 \" 456 \"";
```

It'd make a reasonalbe difference if I could remove this noise somehow.  The reason is that the escape sequence \ and the double quote have meaning in a domain specific language (DSL) that we're using.  Sometimes it's convenient to throw some syntax inline into a C# string.

What I'd like is a way to tell .net not to touch it.  Perhaps some kind of catch all via the DLR?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within a C# literal, there's nothing you can to - don't forget this is all done at *compile-time*.

If you don't use single quotes, you could always do:

```
var s = "123 ' 456 '".Replace("'", "\"");
```

(Or choose some other character you don't use much, and replace that afterwards instead.)

Other than that, avoiding storing lots of data in your source code helps a lot with this sort of thing - for test data, I often use an embedded resource and load that in at execution time.

Comment: that's an option I've considered... but... a number of special purpose charactrers are used by the DSL already (everyone seems to go for the obvious unused character).  Something unexpected like a £ might work.  Different keyboard issues though for cross continent.

Answer (score 4):

I don't suppose you could just read them in from a file or database?

Comment: script files work okay... but often it's good to blend C# with the DSL... and the clearest way to follow the logic is on one page.  Files/database are my only fallback right now.  They can do Razor... so why not another basic parsed based syntax as well?  Like I'd even be happy with XML tags.  <scr></scr>  just don't mess with what's inside some parser based convention please .net.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, there's definitely a way to do that, and I use it all the time for exactly that reason.

You create a string resource collection (open Project Properties, Resources, make sure it's on Strings) and put your literal strings in there.  Then, when you need one of those strings, use the `Properties.Resources.{insert string resource name}` reference to collect it in a pure and unadulterated form!

Comment: that's something I haven't explored yet.  Isn't this similar to a script file though?  Can the contents of the resource appear inline with the other C# code -- at least for completeness, if not for editing?

Comment: You use the 'Properties.Resources.MyStringResourceName' reference just like a local constant reference, it's just a property reference to the compiler/IDE.  Mouseover will show the contents of the string.  So it really isn't anything at all like a script file and is much more like a class defined for you just to hold constant values.  Very handy, and highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, I'll mention that you can use hex in a C# string, so in this case, `\x0022`. Note that you can omit the leading 0's if the character immediately following isn't hex.

Comment: that's interesting.  Pity we can't change some of the conventions though.  Heard they are considering "compiler as a service" over at MS.  Perhaps there's some new stuff comming our way.